# Не загружается сайт при переходе по ссылке

Tags: php, html

При переходе на сайт по ссылке http://example.ru (пример) на главную страницу и после на любую другую страницу, то всё нормально, но если взять ссылку например http://example.ru/daytime, то возникает такая ошибка:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in /home/dxkokqgr/public_html/apps/system/lib/system/dbc.php on line 206
Не могу понять из-за чего такое может быть, так как если перейти на на главную страницу и потом уже на данную страницу, то всё нормально, но если скопировать ссылку и вставить в другом браузере или с другого устройства, то выводит данную ошибку. Но на главную страницу заходит с любого браузера и устройства. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема и как можно решить.

Comment: ну, для начала, надо открыть файл /home/dxkokqgr/public_html/apps/system/lib/system/dbc.php на строке 206. Вероятно,  вы обращаетесь к результам запроса, который вернул ошибку. Посторите ошибки mysql

Comment: Как можно узнать из за какого запроса возникла ошибка? В файле, эта строчка такая: "public function fetch(&$stmt) {
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }"

Comment: смотрите стек в отлатчике, например. К сожалению, нельзя у библиотек mysql попросить текст запроса

Comment: Можете подсказать, как можно посмотреть?

Comment: Получилось исправить, дело было в сессиях, при загрузке главной страницы создаются сессия, которые потом используются, а при заходе сразу на другую ссылку, эти сессии не создавались и запрос не работал